# Linker errors when using LLVM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to use LLVM to build a compiler backend, but I've gotten mired in linker errors. Currently all I attempt to do is include LLVMContext.h (I'm doing the [IBM tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-createcompilerllvm1/index.html)), but this gives me the following linker error:

```sh
$ g++ -o compiler *.o -L/home/jakob/llvm2/lib/*.a -lantlr4-runtime
BayesBaseListener.o:(.data.rel+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'compiler' failed
make: *** [compiler] Error 1
```

Any idea how to configure LLVM correctly so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

The option `-L` is to add a *path* that the linker uses to search for libraries. The option `-l` (lower-case L) is to tell the linker to link with a specific library.

For your case though, if you want to link with all static libraries in a specific location, just list the library files as input files:

```
g++ -o compiler *.o /home/jakob/llvm2/lib/*.a -lantlr4-runtime
```

Note that I don't use the `-L` option.

Comment: Okay thanks, but now I'm getting this error. /usr/bin/ld: /home/jakob/llvm2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Error.cpp.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 21)                   /home/jakob/llvm2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format